# Internal database for tiny VB application

Tags: vb.net

I am writing VB utility which will manage reminders and display them at required date. What is recommended approach for internal database implementation? Are there VB built-in mechanism for such purpose?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: XML/Sql Express/Sql Lite/CSV/Text/MS Access, you pick.

Comment: I'd add [SQL Server Compact](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Compact)

Comment: If there are very few items and they will be set values you could use a series of enumerations that would store everything you need.